# Should mostly working but a little bit broken code stay or be deleted?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, asking-questions, broken-code

I posted the question [Parsing structured text in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29564/parsing-structured-text-in-java)

At first I thought it was working, later I have found a bug in the code. Should it stay or should it be deleted?

Update: I have fixed the bug in aforementioned question, however, I think this discussion is still relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found a serious bug in my question after posting it](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/found-a-serious-bug-in-my-question-after-posting-it)

Answer (score 14):

> At first I thought it was working, later I have found a bug in the code. Should it stay or should it be deleted?

Since you've thought it was all working *prior to posting it*, it is okay.  Consider this snippet from the FAQ:

> To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?

The non-working aspect of the code is still off-topic, though.  But this shouldn't warrant deletion in and of itself.  With the first point in mind, and the intent of the post *not* solely being about fixing a bug, it can remain here.  However, such bug(s) should still be addressed on Stack Overflow.